# Is there a more canonical way to manipulate a URL path in Go?

Tags: go

I'm working on a system in Go to act as middleware. For some of our URLs in other services that I want to parse and analyze, we've embedded something variable at the beginning of the path.

For instance, imagine for user `amysmith` we might have the path `/amysmith/edit/profile` to edit the user profile of `amysmith`.

For the purposes of this system, I'd like to swap the path to become `/edit/profile`, as if the first part of the path weren't there. Admittedly, this is not ideal, but changing that overall naming is a bigger project for another time.

This is achievable by using `strings.Join` and then prepending a `/` and lopping off the last character. I'd like to do this because it keeps the path format in line with other paths that aren't manipulated, which will always begin with a `/`.

```
func (r Resource) CleanedPath() string {
    parts := strings.Split(r.URL.Path, "/")
    return strings.TrimRight("/" + strings.Join(parts[2:], "/"), "/")
}
```

That approach feels a bit clunky to me. Is there a better more "Go" way to do this?

Comment: I would use gorilla/mux and redirect `/{name}/edit/profile` to `/edit/profile`. No manipulation required.

Comment: Instead of `strings.Join`, you can use `filepath.Join`. It does the same thing, but is more "canonical", and ensures you don't end up with duplicate `/` chars, by, say, joining `/foo/` with `/bar/`

Comment: Without going into too much detail, I've concluded that doing this path manipulation is the stopgap I need now without disrupting a bunch of other things. If I were starting from scratch, totally agree it would be better to not need to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chop off everything before the second `/`.

```
func cleanPath(p string) string {
    if i := strings.IndexByte(p[len("/"):], '/'); i >= 0 {
        return p[i+len("/"):]
    }
    return p
}
```

This approach avoids memory allocations.

Comment: That's definitely less clunky. Why do you think that's more conversant in Go? I'm trying to up my familiarity with the language conventions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that uses no packages:

```
package main

func split(path string, count int) string {
   for n, r := range path {
      if r == '/' { count-- }
      if count == 0 {
         return path[n:]
      }
   }
   return ""
}

func main() {
   { // example 1
      s := split("/amysmith/edit/profile", 2)
      println(s == "/edit/profile")
   }
   { // example 2
      s := split("/amysmith/edit/profile", 3)
      println(s == "/profile")
   }
}
```